# Are there any features on modern motherboards (other than WPBT) that would prevent a totally clean Windows installation?

Tags: windows, motherboard

I just recently learned about Windows Platform Binary Table or WPBT, which allows motherboard manufacturers to bundle software with their motherboards that will be automatically installed by Windows. And while it was ostensibly meant to be used to bundle important drivers, it can and has been used to bundle bloatware or other software with exploitable security flaws.

When I install Windows, it's important to me to have it be as clean as possible, which means no third party software or configurations of any kind, so I can start from a totally fresh, unsullied state when configuring it. So naturally I want to disable WPBT (which luckily appears to be possible on certain motherboards) and prevent anything else like it from tampering with a system.

Are there any other features on modern motherboards that could prevent a new Windows installation from being totally clean?

I'm looking for anything that could be used to bundle drivers or software, or store software, settings, profiles, or other data from a previous Windows installation (for example Wi-Fi networks and passwords, vendor branding, security updates, etc.) in such a way that it would survive completely wiping any drives connected to the motherboard.

Comment: It appears this is the only system that does especially that. Drivers for detected hardware can be downloaded and installed by the OS, but this isn't demanded or initiated by the hardware. A web search shows articles published by Microsoft listing the manageable Device Firmware Configuration Interfaces that may be helpful to your research: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/device-firmware-configuration-interface-windows-settings

Comment: Breaches and vulnerabilities in the Intel Management Engine or legitimate use of [server equivalents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) could easily subvert main CPU control in order to put data into memory and run programs in a way that could "taint" a clean install.

Comment: I understand that this could be seen as a research question, but then I have to ask: Why downvote? Flag or vote to close instead.

Answer (score 0):

There may exist other exploit-vectors than WPBT that haven't been
identified yet. It's impossible to say that it's the only one of its
kind, so here's some information about WPBT.

As WPBT executes at a very early stage of the boot, you can't
do a clean install as long as it's enabled.

It's possible to disable it in Windows by an undocumented method that
includes running this `.reg` update:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager]

"DisableWpbtExecution"=dword:00000001
```

However, this is not very useful if WPBT has already been executed and
already did its job on the current Windows installation.

The only sure-fire method is to introduce this registry update into the
WIM file that is used to install Windows.
You may use
[Disable-WpbtExecution](https://github.com/BiscuitTin/Disable-WpbtExecution)
to do that, then do a clean install with this Windows installation.

Note that there is no knowledge about which hardware vendors use it,
and that some of them disabled it in firmware updates after exploits
were demonstrated for WPBT. Note also that with Windows evolving,
it's unknown how long will these Github projects stay useful.

Resources:

- Github project
  [Jamesits / dropWPBT](https://github.com/Jamesits/dropWPBT?tab=readme-ov-file)
- [persistence—info.github.io](https://persistence-info.github.io/Data/wpbbin.html)